# using PNG image as cursor in Windows Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to use a PNG as cursor in .NET.
I have set the Access modifier of the resource Public.
The following code is not working:

```
 Me.Cursor = New Cursor(My.Resources.oldCursor)
```

It is saying "Resolution failed, cannot New cannot handle these argument"

Please help

Comment: Check out the constructors for the Cursor class. [Cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That msdn page mentions nothing about using a PNG file. Only a CUR file.

Comment: I'm Using Express Edition, I cannot add a Cursor File as mentioned in that page. Right now I am using somewhat similar to generate my own bitmap Text cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'Fisrt convert your image to bmp format
Dim DummyVar As Image = Image.FromFile("image.png")
 Using stream As New MemoryStream()
  DummyVar.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp)
 End Using

Dim frm As New Form
Dim pb As New PictureBox
pb.Image = DummyVar
frm.Cursor = New Cursor(DirectCast(pb.Image, Bitmap).GetHicon())
frm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: there is an Error in the declaration with PB picBox. in key part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the website https://convertio.co/png-cur/ to do a one time conversion of the file.